# Angular2: FilterPipe : Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, angular-pipe

I've been trying to build a filter Pipe for my project, which filters through an array of strings. It is working, but still I'm getting an error. I wonder why that is? I would also like to ask if there is a way to make the filter more universal so I can use it for other strings.

Here is the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Afdelingen} from "../models";

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(afdeling:Afdelingen[]) {
    return afdeling.filter(afd => afd.afdelingsNaam == 'pediatrie');
    }
}
```

My HTML was just for testing, but here it goes:

```
<div *ngFor="let afd of afdeling | filter">
  {{afd.afdelingsNaam}}

</div>
```

I've also added an image so you can see, it's working, yet I'm getting an error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZOA.png)

EDIT: Universal search pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Afdelingen} from "../models";

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(afdeling:Afdelingen[], value:string) {
    if (!afdeling)
      return afdeling;
    return afdeling.filter(afd => afd.afdelingsNaam == value);
  }
}
```

Comment: The first time the filter pipe is called, `afdeling` is probably undefined. You need to check if there is value in `afdeling` in your pipe :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this check in your pipe :

```
transform(afdeling:Afdelingen[]) {
    if (!afdeling)
        return afdeling;
    return afdeling.filter(afd => afd.afdelingsNaam == 'pediatrie');
}
```

So you get rid of breaking exceptions

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. I was also able to make a more universal pipe !

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
   name: 'filterbytag'
 })
export class FilterbytagPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
if (!items) return [];
if (!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
  return items.filter(it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your answer and add some description how/why your code solves the issue. Code-only answers are considered as low quality posts